# rsync lost a folder during local backup

Tags: linux, rsync

When I backup a folder locally with the following script, a subfolder "core" is omitted:

```
mkdir {gsp,dst} 
svn co http://10.0.2.59:8118/svn/gsp/Development-Area/3-SCL/Trunk/TaskServer_Gsp gsp
rsync -auC gsp/* dst/
diff -rq gsp dst
```

The output is:

```
Only in gsp/com.boco.gdpp.taskserver.core/src/com/boco/gdpp/taskserver: core
Only in gsp: .svn
```

The return value of rsync command is 0, which means there's no error. The following is the structure of folder "gsp" and "dst", the "core" is not the deepest subfolder. Why the "core" can't be copied to "dst"?

```
tree -d gsp

gsp
|-- com.boco.gdpp.taskserver.core
|   |-- lib
|   |-- META-INF
|   |   `-- spring
|   `-- src
|       `-- com
|           `-- boco
|               `-- gdpp
|                   `-- taskserver
|                       |-- config
|                       |   `-- exports
|                       |       `-- exceptions
|                       |-- core
|                       |   |-- changenode
|                       |   |   |-- element
|                       |   |   `-- process
|                       |   `-- task
|                       |       `-- util
|                       |-- export
|                       |   |-- bean
|                       |   |   |-- enums
|                       |   |   `-- processdef
|                       |   `-- util
|                       |       `-- processtree
|                       `-- msg
|                           `-- support
|-- com.boco.gdpp.taskserver.gsp.gworkflow
|   |-- libs
|   |-- META-INF
|   |   `-- spring
|   `-- src
...(more folders)

94 directories

tree -d dst
dst
|-- com.boco.gdpp.taskserver.core
|   |-- lib
|   |-- META-INF
|   |   `-- spring
|   `-- src
|       `-- com
|           `-- boco
|               `-- gdpp
|                   `-- taskserver
|                       |-- config
|                       |   `-- exports
|                       |       `-- exceptions
|                       |-- export
|                       |   |-- bean
|                       |   |   |-- enums
|                       |   |   `-- processdef
|                       |   `-- util
|                       |       `-- processtree
|                       `-- msg
|                           `-- support
|-- com.boco.gdpp.taskserver.gsp.gworkflow
|   |-- libs
|   |-- META-INF
|   |   `-- spring
|   `-- src
...(more folders)

88 directories
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-C` option causes `rsync` to ignore files and directories matching various patterns, which includes `core`. This name is usually used for process crash dump files. From the man page:

```
The exclude list is initialized to:

    RCS SCCS CVS CVS.adm RCSLOG cvslog.* tags TAGS .make.state .nse_depinfo *~ #* .#* ,*  _$*  *$  *.old  *.bak  *.BAK
    *.orig *.rej .del-* *.a *.olb *.o *.obj *.so *.exe *.Z *.elc *.ln core .svn/
```

You can override this with:

```
--include=core
```